# Grant access to my local computer form outside

Tags: macos, ip, webserver

I am on OS X El Capitain 10.11.5.
Trying to run web server locally and grant access from somewhere outside.
In order to get access to Internet I use wifi spot.
Firewall is unavailable on my Mac computer.

**ifconfig**

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether f4:5c:89:90:96:7d 
    inet6 fe80::f65c:89ff:fe90:967d%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 10.37.44.92 netmask 0xfffffc00 broadcast 10.37.47.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 6a:00:01:80:39:90 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 6a:00:01:80:39:91 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 06:5c:89:90:96:7d 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether 9a:46:fc:f3:8c:a2 
    inet6 fe80::9846:fcff:fef3:8ca2%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether f6:5c:89:09:14:00 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
vboxnet0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
    inet 192.168.99.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.99.255
```

As you can see my computer ip address inside wifi network is **10.37.44.92**

At the same time Google shows that my public IP is **77.88.196.39**

That's how I run the web server:

```
dmac:solidus-sample dob$ rails s -p 3001
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.7 application starting in development on http://localhost:3001
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-08-09 15:32:15] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-08-09 15:32:15] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-darwin15]
[2016-08-09 15:32:15] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=16366 port=3001
```

I would like to get access to my web server by **http://77.88.196.39:3001**. But now it's not accessible though.

**What have I done?**

When I run the web server in such way (-b key means binding):

```
rails s -p 3001 -b 10.37.44.92
```

I can access to `http://10.37.44.92:3001` from any computer inside the same Wifi network.

But no successful access to the web server from Internet.
Thanks.

Comment: If you don't control the network, you can't control its routing. you'd need to set the wifi to port forward to your internal address. That's not going to happen on public wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need port forward to be viable on outside.
For example you address is : **192.168.1.21** and you want provide you web server on outside, you need check you public IP, in your case it is **77.88.196.39.** So for open web you must open **port 80** on your router. You need go to router setting find window with a port forwarding or some think sounds like that. And next put you local adres **192.168.1.21** and add port 80 and click save. Now you web should be viable on outside. If you don't have access to router contact with your network administrator.

**In your case, You must open 3001 port on router**