# Port forwarding doesn't work for my wifi router

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, ip, wifi-configuration

I have asked similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1111537/grant-access-to-my-local-computer-form-outside?noredirect=1#comment1583163_1111537) before.
My MacBook Pro is connected to Internet through wifi router U.S. Cellular.
My public ip **130.180.XXX.XXX**.

**ifconfig**

```
  prod_deploy git:(master) ifconfig 
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 98:01:a7:ad:64:8f 
    inet6 fe80::9a01:a7ff:fead:648f%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.1.165 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 4a:00:06:cf:15:10 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 4a:00:06:cf:15:11 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 9a:01:a7:da:c9:00 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 0a:01:a7:ad:64:8f 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether e2:5c:85:21:55:1f 
    inet6 fe80::e05c:85ff:fe21:551f%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
vboxnet0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
    inet 192.168.99.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.99.255
```

So my internal address is **192.168.1.165**

On my Macbook Pro a webserver is run on port **3001**. I can access it by **http://localhost:3001**.

I have made mapping on wifi router firewall settings:
[image]
But it didn't help me.

I would like to provide access to my web server for someone outside through address http://130.180.XXX.XXX:3001.

UPDATE:
Seems 3001 is open for **192.168.1.165**:
[image]

Comment: You have two conflicting rules: external port 3001 cannot be mapped to two machines. Delete the mapping to 192.168.99.1 or change the external source port. Also, there may be limitations on loop-back, so check public IP access from a different network. Make sure the firewalls permit port 3001 access on both the client and server machines.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Extra ip address removed. Tried to hit address from outside my network. No success.

Comment: Are you sure the public IP is correct? Have you checked that port 3001 is open in the firewall to public access? Make sure (with `netstat` or another utility) that the web-server is listening on both 192.168.1.165:3001 and 127.0.0.1:3001.

Comment: Hey, @AFH, thank you, again. 3001 is open for 192.168.1.165 but no success for now.

Comment: “My public ip 130.180.XXX.XXX.” – but is it? How did you check this? What does the router’s status page say?

Comment: @DanielB, I put `myip` to google search form and Google say it :) Sorry, what should the status page say?

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, Google alone can’t tell you if you’re behind Carrier-grade NAT (which is *very* likely). Some status page in your router’s web interface would ideally show the WAN IP address. Compare it with the IP address you got from Google.

Comment: @DanielB, thanks a lot but there is no WAN ip info on wifi router admin page.

Comment: There are many web-sites which show your public IP address, such as http://whatismyipaddress.com/ or (for use with `curl` in batch files) curl http://ipecho.net/plain.

Comment: @AFH, yes, and I pointed it out in my question 130.180.XXX.XXX.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't say how or when you determined this. Note that, unless you have contracted for a fixed IP address, the public address can change, so you may need to use a Dynamic IP server.